# Unable to run swagger with CXF on top of spring boot Application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, cxf, swagger-ui

Unable to run swagger with CXF on top of spring boot Application, but it's working fine with spring rest web service.

Comment: what is the issue ?

Comment: There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
javax.ws.rs.core.Response$ResponseBuilder.status(ILjava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response$ResponseBuilder;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below Jars were conflicting with spring boot jars. Just removed below-mentioned jars.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-policy</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-wsdl</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.13</version>
        </dependency>
Added below spring boot jars.

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-service-description-swagger</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```